# Is it possible to see the underlying Ruby code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently doing my Final Year Project so I need to include code as part of the submission. Rails generate directories of different files, rather than a block of code that can be copy pasted. If there isn't is there a workaround to submit Rails code in a presentable manner.

Comment: Are you trying to have an entire rails project in one file?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do! However, the code needs to be presented in the appendix of a report.

Comment: Checkout this blog post: https://christoph.luppri.ch/articles/rails/single-file-rails-applications-for-fun-and-bug-reporting/

Comment: Combining the contents of all the files in a directory into a single file (recursively) is very much possible. But presenting it in an order that makes sense is much more challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible.  Here is an example of where it was done:

https://gist.github.com/clupprich/0e8b816883ca4dac6b7632a9e8351c48

This was done manually though, so if you have an existing application, the only way to do this is manually.

Also, I would not suggest this, as the directory structure is setup the way it is for a reason.

Comment: This answer relies solely on a link and is thus worthless if the link is broken.

Comment: @max The link is merely an example where it has been done.  The answer is in the words following.